# Environment Variables required to setup maven?

Tags: maven

What are the environment variables required by a developer to ensure maven is setup correctly on a machine? are M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME, MVN_HOME and MVN_OPTS all the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to set is `JAVA_HOME` pointing to a JDK installation. The first three do not exist anymore in master. The latter is options passing args to the JVM.

Comment: Thanks Michael , do i also need to add Maven's directory root path to the system variable - PATH ?

Comment: Not the root, but the `bin` if you want call just `mvn` instead of the full path.

Comment: Thanks this helps solve the mystery for now, how may i be abreast of changes to maven moving forward? ( by changes I meant to point at fact that the first three environment variables were in use earlier, but your answer suggests that somethinh changed and they went out of use)